# PyCharm: Unable to see sybase databas schema in DB navigator plugin

Tags: plugins, pycharm

I am trying out the [DB navigator plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800?pr=phpStorm) in pyCharm

My target DB is a Sybase 15.5 server. I have put in correct jdbc driver, connection string url, user name and login. The 'Test' button returns success.

However, the navigator fails to show any schema. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

However i do not see anywhere in the setting windows in related to default schema.

Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: I cannot get PyCharm to integrate with Sybase at all. Were you able to?

Answer (score 0):

DB Navigator is a 3rd party plugin. Any reason you use it instead of built-in DB support?
PyCharm Professional supports Sybase ASE out of the box https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/connecting-to-a-database.html#connect-to-sybase-database

You also seem to be using some very old version so I recommend updating.